# Regex Email and Date

Tags: regex

I have a data dump of emails for work in text files
I wish to extract the contents of the emails using regex.

At the moment i am trying to remove the original requester from the data
The original creater of the email will always have a time stamp against their name but anyone who was cc'd will not

In essence it the emails look like this

John Smith (XYZ RE) (M/DD/YYYY HH:MM PM):

The email format of John Smith (XYZ RE) will appear again further down the email with different people

I have created this inelegant regex to get the email (it works so im happy enough with it and i understand it which is more important)

```
([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+[(]+[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+[)])
```

I have also tried something similiar to retrieve the date but this works for some dates and falls down with others

```
([^\s][0-9]+[/]+[0-9]+[/]+[0-9]+\s+[0-9][:][0-9]+\s+(AM|PM)[)][:])
```

Can anyone help?

Im quite new at Regex and would appreciate a walk through too if you have the time
Im using Notepad++ to test it and then using a java based application to run it

Thanks
John

Comment: Your time only has one 'hour' digit, for one...(actually, re-reading, this may be your whole problem - any date with a 2-digit hour field won't match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all those square brackets, using character classes will suffice.

For the date/time regex, use something like:

```
'\(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+:\d+ (AM|PM)\):'
```

`\d` is similar to `[0-9]` - shorter :)

Note that you need to escape brackets otherwise they will be part of the regex, which will mean group capturing.

Having something in a regex pattern surrounded by brackets `()` will mean anything matched in those brackets will be "captured" (stored in variables for later use). If you're working with large texts, and don't need to access the matched strings (e.g. only replacing or something), then you can avoid capturing by adding `?:` in your brackets, like so:

```
'\(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+:\d+ (?:AM|PM)\):'
                           ^^
```

this won't store the matched letters `AM` or `PM` in a variable, which means slightly better performance for large texts :)

Comment: A little typo (you've got a `:` in excess) : `\(\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+:\d+ (AM|PM)\):`

Comment: corrected it. I'm used to times with seconds as their last item ;)

Comment: Plus, I would escape the AM/PM group, using `(?:AM|PM)`. Anyway, this was the good answer. +1

Comment: Parentheses don't need to be escaped inside character classes, do they? I think OP's current `[)]` works just as well.

Comment: No they don't, but `\(` is shorter and more readable than `[(]`.

Comment: that's right @zessx. but since the OP said they're new to regex, I didn't wanna add too much to it by avoiding group capturing `?:`

Comment: Thank you all zessx, mavili and Michelle for your help...It was becoming very frustrating. I have marked mavilli's answer as the most useful but i learned something from all of you

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing one `+`, by the look of it, which will limit your matches to dates with a single-digit hour field.

```
([^\s][0-9]+[/]+[0-9]+[/]+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+[:][0-9]+\s+(AM|PM)[)][:])
                                        ^
```

You can simplify your regex by replacing `[^\s]` with `\S` and `[0-9]` with `\d`, but since this sounds like a one-time use deal, whatever you find easier to read is probably more appropriate. Neither of those replacements are necessary, they're just shortcuts.

(Also, instead of capturing the "AM" or "PM", you could replace `(AM|PM)` with `[AP]M`, which matches an A or P followed by an M without capturing a group.)

Answer (score 0):

For your date try using this:
`/^(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])\/[0-9]{4} ([0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]) (AM|PM)$/`